# Get current model alias Yii2 in ActiveQuery init()

Tags: yii2

I have some models with their ActiveQuery defined with some default conditions.

```
class ProfileQuery extends \yii\db\ActiveQuery{
    public function init(){
        $this->andOnCondition(['not',[Profile::tableName().'.status'=>2]]);
        parent::init();
    }
...
```

The problem is if in another model search I use a join with an alias the `init()` function of `ProfileQuery` still tries to search `tablename.status`

Is there a way to get the current alias while inside the `init()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible right now. Limited alias support was problem since the beginning of Yii 2, but recently it was postponed to Yii 3 and most likely will not be fixed in Yii 2: https://github.com/yiisoft/active-record/issues/33

There were some attempts to fix this, but none of them has been finalized and merged. If you really need it, you may use some code from these PRs and implement it yourself in custom component or fork:

- https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/pull/10253
- https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/pull/10813
- https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/pull/11646

Since Yii 2.0.16 you may also use [`ActiveQuery::getTableNameAndAlias()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequery#getTableNameAndAlias()-detail) but it probably will be useless in `init()`.

Comment: I can confirm it to be useless in init. Thanks for the infos